# Arrow function is skipped

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I don't see anything wrong with this arrow function but even if I replace position with the number 2, it still doesn't run its internals

```
  const isValidMove = (position) => {
    console.log("a")
    const valid = !isNaN(+position);
    return valid;
  }
```

I don't get anything logged to the console even with this:

```
  const isValidMove = (2) => {
    console.log("a")
    const valid = !isNaN(+position);
    return valid;
  }
```

Comment: How are you *calling* the function? And version 2 is a syntax error.

Comment: Also, which console are you looking at? When I "run" version 2, I get `SyntaxError: missing formal parameter`

Answer (score 2):

You've made a fine arrow function, but you're not calling it properly. `isValidMove` will be a function based on your first snippet. To use it, you just need to call it and pass the `position` argument with `isValidMove(2)`. Try this instead:

```js
const isValidMove = (position) => {
    console.log("a")
    const valid = !isNaN(+position);
    return valid;
  }

console.log(isValidMove(2))
```

Comment: @PositiveGuy Are you saying you never *called* the function...?